# Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/VpcSubnetIds: expected minimum item count: 2, found: 1)"

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am doing the following:

```
const vpc = ec2.Vpc.fromLookup(this, "vpcDefault", { vpcId: "someid" });
const instanceType: ec2.InstanceType = ec2.InstanceType.of(ec2.InstanceClass.T3, ec2.InstanceSize.LARGE);
const subnetGroup = rds.SubnetGroup.fromSubnetGroupName(this, "subnetGroup", "test subnet group")
const secretKey = kms.Key.fromKeyArn(this, "kmsKey", "someresourcearn")

const secretSecret = new secrets.Secret(this, "secretSecret", {
  encryptionKey: secretKey,
  secretName: "onTheSpotGeneratedKeyFromKMS",
});

// create new DB Instance
const dbInstance = new rds.DatabaseInstance(this, "testDbInstance", {
  vpc,
  subnetGroup,
  instanceType,
  allocatedStorage: 10,
  storageEncrypted: true,
  databaseName: "test_cdk_db",
  instanceIdentifier: "test-db",
  engine: rds.DatabaseInstanceEngine.postgres({ version: rds.PostgresEngineVersion.VER_13 }),
});

const dbProxy = new rds.DatabaseProxy(this, "dbProxy", {
  proxyTarget: rds.ProxyTarget.fromInstance(dbInstance),
  secrets: [secretSecret],
  vpc,
});
```

I am seeing the following error:

CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::RDS::DBProxy                           | dbProxy

```
Resource handler returned message: "Model validation failed (#/VpcSubnetIds: expected minimum item count: 2, found: 1)" (RequestToken: XXX, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

The issue seems to be happening when I create the dbProxy. Any ideas?

EDIT: These are my subnets.[image]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear on what you can do?

Comment: @Marcin nope. I have already set the availability zones.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your subnet group is incorrect:

```
subnetGroup = rds.SubnetGroup.fromSubnetGroupName(this, "subnetGroup", "test subnet group")
```

How exactly you've create the group is not shown, but it seems that is has only one subnet. It must have [two subnets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInsta) in **different AZ**:

> Your VPC must have at least **two subnets**. These subnets must be in two **different Availability Zones** in the AWS Region where you want to deploy your DB instance.

Comment: Yea. I thought so as well. I currently have five subnets in two different availability zones.